# GoogleApiClient null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, google-api-client

I try to learn android development and now i developing an app with fused location service.

I got a RunFragment.java class when i want to put the GoogleMap fragment, Textviews with latitude and longitude and some other widgets. 
First of all i want to connect to GoogleApiClient and i created new class that will do all this job and leave RunFragment.java clear. (Is that a good idea??)
When i try to run my app i got this error:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Looper android.content.Context.getMainLooper()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.runtheworld.roman.runtheworld.GoogleAPI.buildGoogleApiClient(GoogleAPI.java:28)
        at com.runtheworld.roman.runtheworld.RunFragment.onCreate(RunFragment.java:39)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2031)
```

There is the relevant classes:

**RunFragment.java**

```
package com.runtheworld.roman.runtheworld;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class RunFragment extends Fragment  {

private static View view;

// TextViews
TextView lat,lon;

// GoogleApi
private GoogleAPI mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleAPI(getActivity());



// Default Constructor
public RunFragment() {
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGoogleApiClient.buildGoogleApiClient();
}
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.Connect();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(view);
    }
    try {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.run_fragment, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {
        // Map already created
    }

    lat = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lat);
    lon = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lon);
    lat.setText(String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.getLat()));
    lon.setText(String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.getLon()));


    return view;
}




}
```

**GoogleAPI.java**

```
package com.runtheworld.roman.runtheworld;


import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class GoogleAPI  implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private Context context;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private boolean isConnected;
// Location
Location mLastLocation;

public GoogleAPI(Context c) {
    context = c;
}


protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.d("MYTAG", "BUILDING GOOGLE API");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

public boolean Connect(){
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    else
    Log.d("MYTAG","GoogleApiClient is already connected!");
    return isConnected;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d("MYTAG", "GOOGLE API CONNECTED!");
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
    }
}

public double getLat(){
    return mLastLocation.getLatitude();
}
public double getLon(){
    return mLastLocation.getLongitude();
}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

}
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: move `mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleAPI(getActivity());` in `onCreate`, before calling `buildGoogleApiClient`

Comment: This solution didn't work. maybe something wrong with my cunstructor in GoogleAPI.java?

Comment: what does *This solution didn't work*  mean

Comment: After the correction it's the same null pointer exception

Comment: did you get rid of `private GoogleAPI mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleAPI(getActivity());` ?

Comment: I changed it to:    private GoogleAPI mGoogleApiClient;

Comment: and in onCreate:

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleAPI(getActivity());
        mGoogleApiClient.buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

Comment: After changing code, what line of code is throwing NPE?

Comment: and you are getting the same crash ?

Comment: In RunFragment class :   lat.setText(String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.getLat()));

Comment: and in GoogleApi class:      return mLastLocation.getLatitude();

Comment: NPE, on which object? mGoogleApiClient?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
            at com.runtheworld.roman.runtheworld.GoogleAPI.getLat(GoogleAPI.java:52)
            at com.runtheworld.roman.runtheworld.RunFragment.onCreateView(RunFragment.java:57)

Comment: `mLastLocation` is null. Did you notice that the stacktrace is different ?

Comment: Kindly check the Logcat, does this line **Log.d("MYTAG", "GOOGLE API CONNECTED!");** is getting executed?

Comment: yes. how can i correct this one?

Comment: Deepika Rajani, GOOGLE API CONNECTED not executed

Comment: I tried to run this app with Genymotion and GOOGLE API CONNECTED executed!!!! why my phone cannot connect google api? 

and this app works only if I put in comments this lines from RunFragment.java:

       lat = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lat);
        lon = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lon);
        lat.setText(String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.getLat()));
        lon.setText(String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.getLon()));

how can I solve this problem? 
add another class to handle the locations or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your initial problem was fixed in the comments, here is how you can complete the functionality.

First, to fix the NPE, make sure that `mLocation` is not null before you reference it:

```
public double getLat(){
    double retVal = 0d;
    if (mLastLocation != null){
       retVal = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
    }
    return retVal;
}
public double getLon(){
    double retVal = 0d;
    if (mLastLocation != null){
       retVal = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

The next problem is that `getLastLocation()` has a high tendency to return null.

The best way to get around that is to register a location listener.

Declare `GoogleAPI` as a location listener:

```
public class GoogleAPI  implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

private Context context;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private boolean isConnected;
```

Then register a listener in `onConnected()` (see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html): for how to set up the values for `minTime`, `fastestTime`, and `distanceThreshold`):

```
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d("MYTAG", "GOOGLE API CONNECTED!");
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);
            if (mLastLocation == null) {
               mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
               mLocationRequest.setInterval(minTime);
               mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(fastestTime);
                                 mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
              mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(distanceThreshold);
              LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }

        }
```

Then add the location changed callback:

```
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

             mLastLocation = location;

     }
```